# Asp.net pagemethods not working with most browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using ASP.net pagemethods. This issue I am having is that it wont work with certain browsers. e.g IE, Opera Safari and the new Firefox. It works with Chrome. I found this but didn't help in my case http://www.carlj.ca/2008/06/18/fixing-firefoxs-ns_error_not_available-error-when-using-pagemethods/ any help would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID=”scManager″ enablepagemethods=”true” runat=”server” />
<asp:Button ID="btnBuyNow" runat="server" Text="Buy Now" OnClientClick="AddProductToCart()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function AddProductToCart() {
      //hard coded values for testing, productId, quantity
      PageMethods.AddProduct(142, 1);
      window.location.href = '../Cart.aspx';
   }
</script>

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void AddProduct(string prodId, string quantity)
{
    //adding product to cart
    //When testing with Chrome breakpoint is hit,
    //All other browsers dont hit break point
    CurrentCart.AddProduct(prodId, quantity);
}
```

Comment: make sure you are not getting errors in console window. may be handler issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better solution to this but this was the only thing that eventually worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddProductToCart() {

  //hard coded values for testing, productId, quantity
  PageMethods.AddProduct(142, 1);

  var millisecondsToWait = 500;
           setTimeout(function () {
               window.location.href = '../Cart.aspx';
           }, millisecondsToWait);
       }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>         $(document).ready(function() {
>             $('#Save').click(InsertClient);
>         }
>     );
>         function InsertClient() {
>             var BizName = $('#txtBizName').val();
>             alert(BizName);
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: "Common.asmx/InsertClient",
>                 type: "POST",
>                 dataType: "json",
>                 data: "{BizName:'" + BizName + "'}",
>                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                 success: function(msg) {
>                     $('#status').html('Id: '+msg['d']['Id']);
>                 },
>                 error: function(e) {
>                     $('#status').innerHTML = "Unavailable";
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     </script> 
>
>
>
> in Common.asmx write webmethod as follow
>
> [WebMethod]
> [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
> public Client InsertClient(string BizName)
> {
>     Client objClient = new Client();
>     objClient.BizName = BizName;
>     InsertData(objClient);
>     return objClient;
> }
> ```